# In Blender 3.3.0 the origin of the object moves outside the object when I have the cloth modifier on, I can't move, how do I fix it?

Tags: modifiers, transforms, object-mode, origin

[image]
Cushion

[image]
deflated cushion when I try to move it with G for Grab

Comment: A cloth simulation is - as the name says - a simulation. If you try to move it after it was simulated, you break the simulation and might end up with messed up geometry. Also the origin is not moving outside the object - usually (e.g. when falling down) the mesh moves away from the origin. That is because the positions of the mesh's vertices are simulated to move into new locations according to the settings of the cloth. The object itself cannot be moved, only the simulated mesh if pin group vertices are for example hooked to a different object.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the info,  I think my issue was also caused by the gravity settings so I have made it zero and it helps.